# API Array Return Type

Tags: c#, arrays, api

I'm working on an existing API, written by a few developers who are no longer at my company. As I understand it, the API is implemented as a dll which communicates through sockets to a server program on localhost. So it Marshals objects back and forth. I have to add a few methods to this API. There are a number of existing methods which return a list of available names (all strings). However, they are all returned as arrays of objects. The code is as follows:

```
[return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT )]
object[] GetAvailableNames( );
```

I'm not really sure why this was done: why not just return an array of strings? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: And how is memory dealt with?

Comment: @leppie it's a safe array judging by the annotations so the CLR can deal with the memory via COM rules.

Comment: @JaredPar: Ah ok, I dont know COM (at all). So the assumption is that the COM process/server will deal with memory?

Comment: @leppie, the one advantage to COM (when done correctly) is that the memory responsibility of an API is well understood from just it's signature.  In this case it would be clear that the allocated the array and the callee was responsible for freeing it.

Comment: @JaredPar: Thank you and thank god I never did have to use COM :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit speculative but it appears the the native API is actually returning a safe array of variant objects, not an array of string.  I believe the proper way to marshal a safe array of variants is indeed to do so as an array of strings.  Even though it contains only strings it's legal for any type to be put into the variant slot.

That being said if you have access to both ends of the code (managed and native), it *may* be better to switch them both to communicate directly with arrays of strings.

Comment: As a bit of a corollary (and perhaps my main concern): If I'm certain that I want to return an array of strings (and not any other type), is there any reason you can think of why I should not just use `string[]`?

Comment: @Smashery, yes.  If it's actually a safe array of variants under the hood then you must marshal it as such.  Else it will lead to memory leaks and / or marshalling errors.  It may just so happen to work with strings but you would be walking a very dangerous and fine line.  Much better to leave as is or change both native and managed sides

Comment: Cheers; I must ask, though: what is a safe array of variants, and why might a .NET `string[]` be one?

Comment: @Smashery a safe array of variant is COM's version of `object[]` in .Net.  It's an array of defined length, understood memory semantics, which can hold any COM object type (in particular any `VARIANT` type).  It provides a defined way to pass arbitrary objects across COM APIs.

Comment: @Smashery and it's not that the safe array is necessarily a `string[]`.  Its instead the CLR marshal's the safe array and does a conversion on each element in the array one at a time.  They all happen to be `string` so it just works out in this case.

Comment: @jaredpar - Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I'm not quite understanding what you're saying about the safe array of variants. My intent is to return a `string[]`. That being the case, when does the CLR marshal a safe array? Since it's only a return type from C# (not a parameter in), wouldn't it be marshalling a string array (since that's the return type)? Admittedly, this is the first time I'm using marshalling, so I may be misunderstanding it. Cheers!

Comment: @Smashery unfortunately they are not a simple subject to explain. Let me try a different angle.  The native API is allocating and returning a safe array whose elements are `VARIANT`. The CLR receives this value and takes the following steps. First it will allocate an `object[]` of equivalent length of the safe array.  Then it will go element by element marshaling the native `VARIANT` into the appropriate managed object. `VARIANT` objects are self describing and the CLR knows how to marshal them. Once it's done it will free the safe array and return the `object[]` to your code.

Comment: @jaredpar - Where did a "native API" come into it? I'm creating a C# API. Why is the CLR *receiving* a safe array? My understanding was that the CLR was *returning* arrays, not receiving them. Again, thanks!

Comment: @SMashery, the `MarshalAs` attributes on the method strongly indicate this API is being backed by a COM object.

Comment: Cool; thanks. Perhaps I don't understand my API :-P (highly likely).

Comment: @JaredPar - Now that I understand my API a bit better, it appears its a .NET API that has "Register for COM interop" ticked. Does that sound right?